# Genesis framework comments broken?

Tags: php, comments, sql

I got a really weird problem. Im using a Child theme which using the Genesis framework. I was using Akismet plugin to stop the spammers and it was workin just fine. Recently i just made a comment by myself to test it and this is where the problem start.

- The comment is showing inside the dashboard and its awaiting
  moderation, but i cant delete, approve, unapprove, move or do
  anything with it. Shortly the only way to make it disappear is
  deleting the comment in phpmyadmin.
- Other thing is, Even if i do 5 comment, only one appearing in the
  dashboard the other 4 just disappear. Not even phpmyadmin showing it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: And what happens when you disable the plugin? How about your discussion settings?

Comment: disable the plugins give me the same result.
Comment must be manually approved
Enable threaded (nested) comments  levels deep
Comment author must fill out name and e-mail 
Allow people to post comments on new articles 
Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks) 
 Show Avatars
These are checked.

Comment: Must have 1 comment approved?

Comment: No. If i write 100 comment only the first one will shown in the dashboard to approve, delete, etc.. the other 99 is like never happend.

Comment: you can search `comment_post` action inside your child theme. If that action exists, that might be causing the issue

Comment: Shame on me for not updating my very own question.Sorry for that. I made the problem for myself. I managed to hook something before the comments and thats what broke my entire comment system.